# get string from beginning up to 2nd underscore php

Tags: php

I have a string, 1006_20170731_1.png I want to get only this portion: 1006_20170731_  How can I get this using php? I'm having troubles on understanding strpos and substr. Can someone please help?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

```
$str = "1006_20170731_1.png";
$parts = explode('_', $str);
$result = $parts[0] . '_' . $parts[1] . '_';
```

Now, `$result` would contain your required string.

**Explanation:**

`explode()` splits the string into an array using the first argument as the delimiter. Then we join the first two parts and add underscores between them as per your requirement and we have the result.

Please check the appropriate reference docs:
[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

---

**For a more general approach:**

```
$str = "1006_20170731_1.png";
$delimiter = '_';
$parts = explode($delimiter, $str);

// if we only need to take the first n parts
$n = 2;
$firstNparts = array_slice($parts, 0, $n);
$result = implode($delimiter, $firstNparts) . $delimiter;
```

Now your `$result` would contain the first `n` parts separated by the delimiter as required.

Docs:
[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: While your answer does work for this specific use-case, you should try to write answers that more generally helpful and work more dynamically in hopes that it can help other readers with slightly different use-cases

Comment: Yes it's better ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
function trimStringEndingByDelim($str, $delim = "_", $endingDelim = true) {

    //explode string into an array of every value between the delimiter
    $explodedString = explode($delim, $str);
    //remove the very last array element (in your case "1.png")
    array_pop($explodedString);

    //glue the remaining array elements back together with the delimiter
    $implodedString = implode($delim, $explodedString);

    //if $endingDelim is true return the string with the delimiter glued to the end
    //if it is false, just return the string
    if($endingDelim) return $implodedString.$delim;
    return $implodedString;

}
```

it takes your string and converts it to an array at the point of every underscore, removes the last array element, and then returns the string with the underscores re-added using the implode function.

You can also pass a different delimiter if you want, for example `$var = removeEnd("this|is|a|string|1.png","|")` would return `this|is|a|string|`

You can toggle the ending delimiter by setting the 3rd parameter to "false", by default it adds the delimiter at the end.

`$var = removeEnd("this|is|a|string|1.png","|",false)` would return `this|is|a|string`

An added bonus to using this function is it works no matter how many of the delimiters are used, as long as you always want to trim the very last delimiter only. This could very easily be modified to remove however many off the end that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example: https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_jopekz.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_jopekz.php
/**
 * Substrings
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421271/get-string-from-beginning-up-to-2nd-underscore-php
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$str = '1006_20170731_1.png';
$dlm = '_';
$arr = explode($dlm, $str);
array_pop($arr);
$new = implode($dlm, $arr) . $dlm;

echo PHP_EOL . $str;
echo PHP_EOL . $new;
```

Answer (score -1):

`pathinfo` function can do what you are looking for. Please refer to the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php.

Comment: `path_info` can get `1006_20170731_1` OP wants `1006_20170731_`

Comment: Couldn't tell if that was a typo or not... Why would someone want the trailing `_`? But you are correct that this function isn't what he wants if his intent is exactly what it is written in the original question.